# Rails 4 + Form object: Is multiple levels of form objects poor design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an e-commerce site and I'm on the checkout portion. The required checkout info (shipping address, billing_address, billing_info) will all happen in a single page in one form, so I thought this would be a good opportunity to learn about Form Objects and try it out.

I followed the code from the tutorial I found here: http://pivotallabs.com/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit/

My form object looks like this right now with just shipping and billing address parameters:

```
class CheckoutForm
  include Virtus.model
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  attribute :purchase_id, Integer
  attribute :shipping_address_first_name, String
  attribute :shipping_address_last_name, String
  attribute :shipping_address_street_address, String
  attribute :shipping_address_street_address2, String
  attribute :shipping_address_zip_code, String
  attribute :shipping_address_city, String
  attribute :shipping_address_state_id, Integer
  attribute :shipping_address_phone_number, String


  attribute :billing_address_first_name, String
  attribute :billing_address_last_name, String
  attribute :billing_address_street_address, String
  attribute :billing_address_street_address2, String
  attribute :billing_address_zip_code, String
  attribute :billing_address_city, String
  attribute :billing_address_state_id, Integer
  attribute :billing_address_phone_number, String

  validates_presence_of :shipping_address_first_name
  validates_presence_of :shipping_address_last_name
  validates_presence_of :shipping_address_street_address
  validates_presence_of :shipping_address_zip_code
  validates_presence_of :shipping_address_city
  validates_presence_of :shipping_address_state_id

  validates_presence_of :billing_address_first_name
  validates_presence_of :billing_address_last_name
  validates_presence_of :billing_address_street_address
  validates_presence_of :billing_address_zip_code
  validates_presence_of :billing_address_city
  validates_presence_of :billing_address_state_id

  validate do
    [shipping_address, billing_address].each do |object|
      unless object.valid?
        object.errors.each do |key, values|
          errors[key] = values
        end
      end
    end
  end


  def purchase
    @purchase ||= Purchase.find(purchase_id)
  end

  def shipping_address
    @shipping_address ||= purchase.build_shipping_address(
      first_name: shipping_address_first_name,
      last_name: shipping_address_last_name,
      street_address: shipping_address_street_address,
      street_address2: shipping_address_street_address2,
      city: shipping_address_city,
      zip_code: shipping_address_zip_code,
      state_id: shipping_address_state_id,
      phone_number: shipping_address_phone_number
    )
  end

  def billing_address
    @billing_address ||= purchase.build_billing_address(
      first_name: billing_address_first_name,
      last_name: billing_address_last_name,
      street_address: billing_address_street_address,
      street_address2: billing_address_street_address2,
      city: billing_address_city,
      zip_code: billing_address_zip_code,
      state_id: billing_address_state_id,
      phone_number: billing_address_phone_number
    )
  end


  def save
    return false unless valid?
    create_objects
  end

  private

    def create_objects
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        shipping_address.save!
        billing_address.save!
      end
    rescue
      false
    end

end
```

As you can see, there are a lot of repeats for prefixes since I don't have the luxury of using embedded hashes as params. I was thinking of creating other objects and use composition so that I could embed the params inside `shipping_address[first_name]` or something.

Here's what I mean:

```
class CheckoutForm
  include Virtus.model
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  attribute :purchase_id, Integer
  attribute :shipping_address, FormAddress #<-- another form object
  attribute :billing_address, FormAddress  #<-- 
  ...


end
```

additional form object to act as shipping_address and billing_address:

```
class FormAddress
  include Virtus

  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attribute :first_name, String
  attribute :last_name, String
  attribute :street_address, String
  attribute :street_address2, String
  attribute :zip_code, String
  attribute :phone_number, String
  attribute :city, String
  attribute :state_id, Integer

  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name

end
```

Would this be a bad design choice, since I'm in theory just building my own version of an `accepts_nested_attributes_for`?